# Heatmap rearrange columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, heatmap

[image: Heatmap as it stands]

I'm creating a heatmap in R and new to the language. Trying to reorder the y axis on this heatmap so that the cities with the most yearly occurrences show up at the top and the least at the bottom, but getting loads of errors, and even once I got past them it didn't change anything. I've tried lots of things already so figured it may be worth asking.

The only relevant variable names: `Month_num` and `Australian_City`. Here's what I've got:

```
# I've included my discarded ideas too, as comments
require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)

add_count(flights, Australian_City)
ggplot(flights, aes(x=Month_num %>% reorder(count.Freq), y=Australian_City)) + geom_bin2d() + scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")) + labs(x="Month", y="Flights per city") + ggtitle("Monthly International Flights Per City")

#city_counts = flights %>% group_by(Australian_City) %>% count()
#ave(age, gender, FUN = length))
#flights %>% mutate(num_by_city=ave(Australian_City, FUN=length))
#flights$Australian_City <- flights$Australian_City %>% reorder(flights$n)
#flights <- transform(flights, count=table(Australian_City)[Australian_City])
#flights %>% mutate(num_by_city= case_when(city_counts$Australian_City==Australian_City ~ city_counts$n))
#flights %>% mutate(visit_count = sum(flights$))
```

I can see one of those discarded ideas working, but I've got no idea how :(. Both `Month_num` and `Australian_City` are factors, but the Month is stored as integers `1` through `12`. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your situation.
Create dataset:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Adelaide <- sample(1:300, 12, replace=TRUE)
Darwin <- sample(1:300, 12, replace=TRUE)
Calms <- sample(1:300, 12, replace=TRUE)
Canberra <- sample(1:300, 12, replace=TRUE)
Melbourne <- sample(1:300, 12, replace=TRUE)

data <- data.frame(Adelaide, Darwin, Calms, Canberra, Melbourne)
data$Month <- format(ISOdatetime(2000,1:12,1,0,0,0),"%b")

       Adelaide Darwin Calms Canberra Melbourne Month
1        91    148    10      246        45   gen
2       175    156   247      118         1   feb
3       244    232    18      287        74   mar
4       123      5    75      194       136   apr
5       142    267    19      155        75   mag
6       166    292   263      266       187   giu
7        18     72    61       83       197   lug
8       294     97    69       15         3   ago
9       234    135    80        8       267   set
10      181    134    54       64       203   ott
11      232    197    50      145        39   nov
12      177     20    68       32       299   dic
```

Then gather it:

```
data <- gather(data, "City","Count",1:5) # change 5 with your actual number of cities
data$Month <- as.character(data$Month)
data$Month <- factor(data$Month, levels=unique(data$Month))

data$City <- as.character(data$City)
data$City <- factor(data$City, levels=unique(data$City))

     Month   City   Count
1    gen  Adelaide    91
2    feb  Adelaide   175
3    mar  Adelaide   244
4    apr  Adelaide   123
5    mag  Adelaide   142
6    giu  Adelaide   166
7    lug  Adelaide    18
8    ago  Adelaide   294
9    set  Adelaide   234
10   ott  Adelaide   181
11   nov  Adelaide   232
12   dic  Adelaide   177
13   gen    Darwin   148
14   feb    Darwin   156
15   mar    Darwin   232
16   apr    Darwin     5
17   mag    Darwin   267
18   giu    Darwin   292
..   ...    .....    ...
```

Then plot the heatmap (not ordered):

```
ggplot(data, aes(x= Month, y = City , fill= Count)) + geom_tile()
```

[image: Heatmap_normal]

Finally, you can arrange the rows in a way that cities with the most yearly occurrences show up at the top:

```
     Calms  Melbourne  Canberra    Darwin  Adelaide 
     1014      1526      1613      1755      2077 

ggplot(data, aes(x= Month, y = reorder(City, Count) , fill= Count)) + geom_tile()
```

[image: Heatmap_ordered]

Comment: @LachShed Did you fix the problem?